# How to pass data between 2 view controllers in storyboards?

Tags: ios, storyboard, initialization

Let's assume we have 2 view controllers named *ViewControllerA*
  and *ViewControllerB*.

I have following intialization mechanism when I did not use the storyboard.

//ViewControllerA.h

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController

@end
```

//ViewControllerA.m

```
@implementation ViewControllerA

- (IBAction)showViewControllerB:(id)sender {
    ViewControllerB *vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcB animated:YES];
 }

@end
```

//ViewControllerB.h

```
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;

 @end
```

//ViewControllerB.m

```
@interface ViewControllerB()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;//Private scope.

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    self = [self init];
    if(self)
    {
        _title = title;
    }
    return self; 
}

@end
```

**How can I achieve this using storyboards without declaring the title property in public scope (ViewControllerB.h)?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "**achieve this using storyboards**"?

Comment: @Popeye yes, but without declaring the ViewControllerB's title property in .h file. It should be in .m file(private scope) as mentioned in above example.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: @Popeye, what clarification you needed from the above question?I am able to explain my problem.

Comment: Well we get you want a private property or something o_O from the comments but where do you say that in your question and what does that have to do with storyboards? Your question just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) to access the property.

```
- (IBAction)showViewControllerB:(id)sender 
{
    ViewControllerB *viewcontroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerB"]; // corresponding to the storyboard identifier
    [viewcontroller setValue:@"Hello World" forKey:@"title"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard=self.storyboard;

ViewControllerB *vc=(ViewControllerB*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Scene_Id"];

[vc setTitle:@"your Text"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Please check my question, title property must be in ViewControllerB.m file, not in .h file(Private scope).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep the property private you could attach data to `vcB` object using [`objc_setAssociatedObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5280117/70350). Or you could save the property in the AppDelegate instead, and fetch it from there when ViewControllerB initializes.